# Creating a Layout with a bent line

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I think its the best posting a picture of what I want to do. I want a layout like this:

[image]

This one on the picture I have already made, but I think I made it in the worst possible way. Here is what I have done so far:

Create a Shape (oval) (game_top_circle.xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then create the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.assigame.nidhoegger.assigame.GamePlayfieldCards"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/game_top_circle"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:paddingTop="950dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-300dp"
        android:paddingRight="-300dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView4"
        android:background="#ff000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The black are beneath the bent line shall be a horizontal scroll area. Can somone point me in the right direction how this is done better?

Comment: reduce `android:paddingTop="950dp"` to `android:paddingTop="900dp"`

Comment: Thats not exactly what ive been looking for. Im looking more for a way not to use obscure Trial-and-error values. Maybe theres a way to create a shape that i want so i have only to set the source to it in the imageview without playing with padding and margin stuff.

Comment: you can use an image like it and stretch it depending on device

Comment: Thats what id like to avoid. So you say theres no better attempt than this?

Comment: another attempt is to create custom view and use its ondraw method to draw your own shapes in canvas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77499/discussion-between-nidhoegger-and-scion-of-ikshvaku).